# semantic-ui ignores e.preventDefault in modal dialog

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I'm trying to use semantic-ui to block transfer away from a page with a modal dialog, however, e.preventDefault() appears not to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Modal Block HREF</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css">
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<a class="dirty" href="http://www.microsoft.com">Microsoft</a>
<a class="dirty" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>

<div id="confirmmodal" class="ui small modal">
    <div class="header">FIRST</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="left">
            The first of many interesting things
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="ui black deny button">
            Cancel
        </div>
        <div class="ui positive button">
            OK
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="savemodal" class="ui small modal">
    <div class="header">SECOND</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="left">
            The second of many interesting things
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="ui black deny button">
            Cancel
        </div>
        <div class="ui positive button">
            OK
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.dirty').on('click', function(e, t) {
    // This works...
    //if (confirm('Are you sure')) {
    //    console.log("allow transfer");
    //}
    //else {
    //    console.log("block transfer");
    //    e.preventDefault();
    //}

    // This does NOT work
    $('#confirmmodal')
        .modal({
            onApprove: function () {
                console.log("allow transfer");
            },
            onDeny: function () {
                console.log("prevent transfer");
                   e.preventDefault();
                }
            })
        .modal('show');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What seems to happen is the link is responded to immediately before the dialog even appears, and even if I click on Cancel quickly, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the first click from submitting the page.  Use the below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.dirty').on('click', function(e, t) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        $('#confirmmodal') .modal({
            onApprove: function () {
                console.log("allow transfer"); 
                window.location = href;
            }, 
            onDeny: function () {
                console.log("prevent transfer");
            } 
        }) .modal('show'); 
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: The only issue is that a rectangle is left around the tab that the user clicked on, like a focus rect; anyway to prevent that?

Comment: @imekon that is probably due to "outline". You can turn that off via css.  I believe "outline: none;" will work.  Just apply it to whatever element you want (or everything)